# How to rewrite URLs in vagrant using .htaccess or any other method?

Tags: .htaccess, vagrant

Recently I've been using vagrant for a university assignment and we have to use the single entry point concept by routing everything through the index.php page. Naturally this makes Urls quite ugly (for eg: index.php?page=bookings). So I tried using .htaccess files which work flawlessly with standard php using Xampp.

But I can't get the URLs to redirect in vagrant when I place the .htaccess file in the public folder where the index.php resides.
The file path is vagrant\websites\default\public.htaccess

.htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Is it not working because Vagrant uses Nginx server?
Any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the url you are hitting? Please post a sample of url here, thank you.

Comment: about should redirect to index.php?page=about .
RewriteRule about index.php?page=about .
The above rewrite rule would be used if the wildcards weren't used

Comment: `Is it not working because Vagrant uses Nginx server?` => if what your saying is that you know that your vagrant machine used for this project is running nginx, the answer is [yes](/questions/35766676/how-can-i-use-an-htaccess-file-in-nginx)

Comment: @Zeitounator ohh. thanks